# how to auto pass parameter as release branch the branch is under master it need to build tag in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

example: I have a master branch under master we have created number of release branches **release/1.0, release/1.1, …..** now I have to auto pass the latest release branch in tag parameter

Comment: Hope this helps: https://tomd.xyz/jenkins-dynamic-git-branch/

Comment: which ever the document have it will show only master. it need to take automatically if latest branch is release/1.10 what ever the latest branch is there it need to take to Tag parameter